# Execute Windows command from Cygwin bash script

Tags: windows, bash, batch-file, command-line, cygwin

I am using Windows with Cygwin installed and have a bash script.  Since Cygwin's implementation of the Unix `cp` command/program is flawed for Windows on default installation (fails to preserve Windows permissions unless Cygwin is installed with certain flags), I would like to issue Windows' native `copy` command from the bash script instead.

Is there a way for me to issue this (and possibly any generic Windows Command Prompt command) **and** be able to handle errors (say `copy` fails due to UAC, file not found, network drive unreachable, etc.) from within the bash script?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have cygwin right now but one of the following should works

```
./test.bat params
cmd /c test.bat params
cmd /c copy /?
```

Remember the quotes/double quotes can be interpreted differently between `cmd` and `bash`.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows BAT :

```
copy "YourFile.xyz" "ToDestinationPath(.xyz)" && (
              Echo Copy ==^> Success
                  ) || (
              Echo Copy ==^> Failed)
```